# Django selenium select form options in <select>

Tags: django-testing

How do you use selenium in Django to choose and select an option in a `<select>` tag of a form?

This is how far I got:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()

def test_project_info_form(self):
    # set url
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/tool/project_info/')
    # get module select
    my_select = self.browser.find_element_by_name('my_select')
    #! select an option, say the first option !#
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So this post was very useful:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver

Basically I had to target the `<select>` and `<option>` by `xpath` directly, followed by a click event:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//select[@id='my_select_id']/option[text()='my_option_text']"
    ).click()
```

Or I could have targeted the  by index:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//select[@id='my_select_id']/option[2]"
    ).click()
```

I hope this is helpful to someone with a similar problem.